# Mysql csv file selecting multiple value in one column

Tags: mysql, csv, import, workbench

```
,PMID,LastName,ForeName,Initials,Affiliation
0,1,"['Makar', 'McMartin', 'Palese', 'Tephly']","['A B', 'K E', 'M', 'T R']","['AB', 'KE', 'M', 'TR']",
,,,,,
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTFRc.png)

this is the csv file

I want to divide this to look like this

```
PMID     Name            Affiliation
 1       Makar_A B_AB
 1       MCMartin_K E_KE
 1       Palese_M_M
 1       Tephly_T R_TR
```

below is the code I wrote in mysql workbench

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AuthorTBL;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AuthorTBL
( PMID varchar(100),
  LastName varchar(50),
  ForeName varchar(50),
  Initials varchar(50),
  Affiliation varchar(250)
  );
  
LOAD DATA INFILE 'abcd.csv'
INTO TABLE AuthorTBL
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@num, @PMID, @LastName, @ForeName, @Initials, @Affiliation)
SET
    PMID = @PMID,
    LastName = @LastName,
    ForeName = @ForeName,
    Initials = @Initials,
    Affiliation = @Affiliation;
```

How can I change my code to make it work?

Comment: Does CSV contains only one row with data?

Comment: no but It was too long so I shorted it.
,PMID,LastName,ForeName,Initials,Affiliation
0,1,"['Makar', 'McMartin', 'Palese', 'Tephly']","['A B', 'K E', 'M', 'T R']","['AB', 'KE', 'M', 'TR']",
1,2,"['Bose', 'Sarma']","['K S', 'R H']","['KS', 'RH']",
2,3,"['Smith', 'Bryant']","['R J', 'R G']","['RJ', 'RG']",
3,4,"['Wiesmann', 'DiDonato', 'Herschkowitz']","['U N', 'S', 'N N']","['UN', 'S', 'NN']",
4,5,"['Hendrickson', 'Ward']","['W A', 'K B']","['WA', 'KB']",

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` has no mechanism to expand those arrays and create multiple rows. You can't do what you want this way. I suppose you might be able to deal with it using a `TRIGGER`, but frankly it would be much easier to handle it in some other language like PHP. The other alternative is to get whatever produced this cock-eyed format to produce a more conventional CSV file.

Comment: ok I will search for different method

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular *I suppose you might be able to deal with it using a TRIGGER,* Trigger cannot help. OP needs to convert one source row to a lot of rows.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?